# How to target parent elements among multiple sub child elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

HTML -

```
<div class="windows" id="window'+divCount+'"> 
  <p id="windowName'+divCount+'"></p> 
  <p id="para'+divCount+'">Source</p> 
</div> 
<div class="windows" id="window'+divCount+'"> 
  <p id="windowName'+divCount+'"></p> 
  <p id="para'+divCount+'">Source</p> 
</div> 
<div class="windows" id="window'+divCount+'"> 
  <p id="windowName'+divCount+'"></p> 
  <p id="para'+divCount+'">Source</p> 
</div> 
<div class="windows" id="window'+divCount+'"> 
  <p id="windowName'+divCount+'"></p> 
  <p id="para'+divCount+'">Source</p> 
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT -

```
$.contextMenu({
      selector: ".windows",
      selectableSubMenu: true,
      callback: function(key, options) {
        var m = "clicked: " + key;
        window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m);
      },
      items: {
        "delete": {
          name: "Delete",
          callback: function() {
            $('<div style="font-family:Poppins;" title="Delete Window"> <p></span>This window will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p></div>').dialog({
              resizable: false,
              height: "auto",
              width: 400,
              modal: true,
              buttons: {
                Cancel: function() {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "Delete": function() {
                  $(this.parentNode).remove();
                },
              }
            });
    
          }
        },
    
        "sep1": "---------",
    
        "SB": {
          name: "Send Back",
          callback: function() {
            var index = $(this).css("z-index");
            if (index != 50) {
              index = parseInt(index) - 50;
              $(this).css("z-index", index);
            } else {
              $(this).css("z-index", "50");
            }
          }
        },
    
        "SF": {
          name: "Bring Front",
          callback: function() {
            var index = $(this).css("z-index");
            index = parseInt(index) + 50;
            $(this).css("z-index", index);
          }
        },
    
        "Du": {
          name: "Duplicate",
          callback: function() {
            $(this).attr("Window" + 1);
            $(this).clone().appendTo(container);
          }
        },
    
        "Edi": {
          name: "Edit",
          callback: function() {
    
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

`divcount` is the windows created count. I am using context menus for individual changes need in the `div class="windows"`, inside the context menu, I have used jQuery Dialog widgets. When I click delete in the dialog box, I want to `remove()` only the div/window that was right clicked and not all of them. I have tried `this.parentElement`, but that removes the context menu and not the div. How do I target and remove the right clicked div? Here is a fiddle of my code -

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```js
var main = document.getElementById("maincontent");
var divCount = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#grid_settings").hide();
  $(main).append('<div id="videoWall" class="videoWallContainer"></div>');
  var container = document.getElementById("videoWall");
  container.style.width = "100%";
  container.style.height = "76vh";
  container.style.backgroundColor = "#1B1B1B";
  container.style.position = "relative";
  container.style.fontSize = "0";
  container.style.border = "1px solid white";
  console.log($(window).height());
  windowProperties(container, 0, 0, 300, 300)

});

function windowProperties(containment, x, y, width, height) { //New Window Style and jQuery Functions

  var container = document.getElementById("videoWall");
  var x, y;
  var currentX = x;
  var currentY = y;
  var currentWidth = width;
  var currentHeight = height;

  $(containment).append('<div class="windows" id="window' + divCount + '"><p id="windowName' + divCount + '"></p><p id="para' + divCount + '">Source</p></div>');
  var nWindow = document.getElementById('window' + divCount);
  var paragraph = document.getElementById('para' + divCount);
  var windowName = document.getElementById('windowName' + divCount);


  paragraph.style.color = "black";
  paragraph.style.fontSize = "20px";
  paragraph.style.fontWeight = "bold";
  paragraph.style.padding = "20px";
  paragraph.style.textAlign = "center";
  paragraph.style.fontFamily = "poppins";



  nWindow.style.width = currentWidth + "px"; //680
  nWindow.style.position = "absolute";
  nWindow.style.height = currentHeight + "px"; //294.75
  nWindow.style.opacity = "0.5";
  nWindow.style.background = "#f8f8f8";
  nWindow.style.outline = "2px solid Black";
  nWindow.style.zIndex = "999";
  nWindow.style.top = currentY + "px";
  nWindow.style.left = currentX + "px";

  $.contextMenu({
    selector: ".windows",
    selectableSubMenu: true,
    callback: function(key, options) {
      var m = "clicked: " + key;
      window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m);
    },
    items: {
      "delete": {
        name: "Delete",
        callback: function(itemKey, opt) {
          $('<div style="font-family:Poppins;" title="Delete Window"> <p></span>This window will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p></div>').dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: "auto",
            width: 400,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
              Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
              },
              "Delete": function() {
                opt.$trigger.remove();
                $(this).dialog("close");
              },
            }
          });

        }
      },

      "sep1": "---------",

      "SB": {
        name: "Send Back",
        callback: function() {
          var index = $(this).css("z-index");
          if (index != 50) {
            index = parseInt(index) - 50;
            $(this).css("z-index", index);
          } else {
            $(this).css("z-index", "50");
          }
        }
      },

      "SF": {
        name: "Bring Front",
        callback: function() {
          var index = $(this).css("z-index");
          index = parseInt(index) + 50;
          $(this).css("z-index", index);
        }
      },

      "Du": {
        name: "Duplicate",
        callback: function() {
          $(this).attr("Window" + 1);
          $(this).clone().appendTo(container);
        }
      },

      "Edi": {
        name: "Edit",
        callback: function() {

        }
      }
    }
  });

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.7.1/jquery.contextMenu.min.css">

<div id="maincontent">

</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.7.1/jquery.contextMenu.min.js"></script>
```

You can refer to the source `.window` element for the `contextMenu` by using the `items.delete` [callback options `$trigger` property](http://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/docs.html#callback) (`opt.$trigger`).

Comment: Exactly what i needed! Thanks!